# Append custom validator to an extra field

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-admin

I'm looking for a way to check extra field if its input is not unique. Using pure Flask+WTForms I could create form class like that:

```
class EditProfileAdminForm(Form):
    nickname = StringField('Nickname (login)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if field.data != self.user.email and \
                User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Email is already registered.')
```

But how do I create/modify form class when I implement custom ModelView? Adding extra field to ModelView is looking as follows:

```
class UserModelView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('f_email', 'nickname')

    form_extra_fields = {
        'f_email': StringField('Email')
    }
```

and simple defining validate_f_email doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two ways to validate field value unicity against specified model.

#### First way

Override on_model_change() function. This function perform some actions before a model is created or updated

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if form.f_email.data != model.email and \
                User.query.filter_by(email=form.f_email.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Email is already registered.')
        model.email = form.f_email.data
```

Disadvantage of this method of this method is that error message is shown at the top of the page:
[image]

#### Second way

I have also found that flask-admin provides Unique validator. Everything you need is to append it to validators list:

```
class UserModelView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('f_email', 'nickname')

    form_extra_fields = {
        'f_email': StringField('Email', validators=[Email(), Unique(db.session,
                                                                    models.User,
                                                                    models.User.email)])
    }
```

Now error message is shown as it have to:
[image]